# PHP - Check box does not implode and getting updated in the database

Tags: php, html, sql

Well what my goal is to get the values of the selected checkboxes and then implode the array so that it is in a string format and then I could already insert in the database.

```
echo "  
<div class='modal fade' id='modalRejectCEO' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
          <h4 class='modal-title'>Reject ".$strings["project"].": ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0]."</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
          <h5>Please specify the reason for rejecting the project ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0].". (eg. Reason is too vague)</h5>
          <form>
          <input type='checkbox' name='projectInfo[]' value='location'><b>Location: </b>".nl2br($projectDetail->pro_street_address[0]).", ".nl2br($projectDetail->pro_city_province[0])." <br><br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='projectInfo[]' value='date'><b>Date: </b>".$projectDetail->pro_start_date[0]." - ".$projectDetail->pro_end_date[0]." <br><br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='projectInfo[]' value='summary'><b>Project Description: </b><br><br>".nl2br($projectDetail->pro_description[0])."<br><br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='projectInfo[]' value='objectives'><b>Objectives: </b>".nl2br($projectDetail->pro_objectives[0])."<br><br>
          </form>

            <div class='input-group'>
                <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1' style='width:500px;'>Reason for Rejection:</span>
                <input type='text' id='reasonCEO' name='reasonCEO' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' placeholder='' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input type='submit' id='rejectCEO' class='btn btn-primary' name='rejectCEO'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ";
```

And this is triggers the update method of SQL

```
    if(isset($_POST['rejectCEO']) && $_POST['reasonCEO'] != ""){
        $selectedReason = implode(', ',$_POST['projectInfo']);

        $query3="UPDATE projects 
        SET project_status = '3', reason = '".$_POST['reasonCEO']."', reason_referrer = '".implode(',',$_POST['projectInfo'])."'
        WHERE id =".$idProj."";      

        retrieveTable($query3);
        header('Location: listprojectsprojectproposal.php');
}
```

Comment: for one thing, you closed off your `</form>` too early. Probably "thee" reason why your code failed.

Comment: Error reporting would have helped you out here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi fred! Please do send it as an answer . Will accept you answer as it solved the problem

Comment: I've posted a community answer which you can accept; it's just as valid an answer, *cheers*. I don't want to make rep anymore, I'm in this for pure honest to goodness "help" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as a community wiki. I don't want rep for it, nor should any be made from it.

---

As I said, you closed off your `</form>` too early.

Error reporting would have helped here also.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Btw, your code's open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement